# You did not select a file to upload, file upload error in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I'm trying to add singer information with image. the information can be successfully added without image but if i try to insert data with image, error occurred with "You did not select a file to upload" message.
My controller function is this...

```
   public function add_edit_singer($id = '')
   {
    if($this->input->post('save_singer_info')){

        $post=$this->input->post();
        $add=array(
        'name'=>$post['sname'],
        'bio'=>$post['bio']
        );

        $img1=$_FILES['photo']['name'];
       if($img1){
        $config['upload_path'] = 'images/singer/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if (!$this->upload->do_upload())
        {
            $error = $this->upload->display_errors();
            $this->session->set_flashdata('info',$error);
            redirect('admin/singer_manager');
        }
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
        $image = $data['upload_data']['file_name'];
        $add['image']=$image;

        }
        else{
            $add['image']='no_image.jpg';
        }

        $table='tbl_singer';
        if($this->singer_manager->add($add,$table)){
         $this->session->set_flashdata('info',"Artist/Band Information Added Successfully.");
         redirect('admin/singer_manager');
        }
        else{
            redirect('admin/singer_manager');
        }

    }
    else{
    $data['main_content']='admin/singer/add_edit_singer_view';
    if($id != '')
            $data['editdata'] = $this->common_model->get_where('tbl_singer', array('id' => $id));
    $this->load->view('admin/include/template_view',$data);
  }
```

}

my Model function is...

```
function add($data,$table){
    $name = $data['name'];
    $res = $this->db->insert($table,$data);
    if($res)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

and my Form is...

```
<form role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo base_url('admin/singer_manager/add_edit_singer/' . $id); ?>"
                          method="post"
                          id="user_form">
                        <table class="table table-hover">
                            <tr>
                              <td>Singer Name</td>
                              <td>
                              <input type="text" class="form-control required" name="sname"
                                 value="<?php if (isset($name)) {
                                     echo $name;
                                 } ?>"/>
                              </td>  
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                              <td>Bio</td>
                              <td>
                                <textarea class="form-control required" name="bio">
                                  <?php if (isset($bio)) {
                                           echo $bio;
                                       } ?>
                                </textarea>
                              </td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                              <td>Image</td>
                              <td>
                              <?php if (isset($image)) {?>
                                <div class="row">
                                  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
                                    <a href="<?php echo base_url().'images/singer/'.$image;?>" class="thumbnail">
                                      <img src="<?php echo base_url().'images/singer/'.$image;?>" width="120" height="140" id="img_prev" />
                                    </a>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                              <?php
                               } ?>

                              <input type="file"  name="photo" size="20" />
                              </td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                              <td colspan="2">
                                <?php if (isset($id)) { ?><input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" /><?php } ?>
                                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="btn_save" name="save_singer_info"value="Save"/>
                                <input type="reset" class="btn btn-info" id="reset"/>
                                <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="Cancel"onclick="history.go(-1)"/>
                              </td>
                            </tr>

                        </table>
                    </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
$this->upload->do_upload()
```

to

```
$this->upload->do_upload('photo')
```

may be it solve the problem